# Is there a way to view wireshark application logs?

Tags: wireshark

I mean the logs of the application and not network traffic. Say, I use a key to decrypt the TLS data, so I specify the location of the key in Preferences > Protocols > TLS > Pre-master secret log file. Now that file could be of the wrong format, or there could be permission issues while reading that file or for whatever reason the traffic is not decrypted.
Is there a way to view such logs? I am using macOS.

Answer (score 0):

I did not find a way to get all application logs on macOS. On Linux, launching Wireshark from terminal does print some logs.
Specifically for TLS logs, a file could be specified in Preferences > Protocols > TLS > TLS debug file.
[image]

The log file gives logs for each frame. Sample:

```
Wireshark SSL debug log 

Wireshark version: 3.4.5 (v3.4.5-0-g7db1feb42ce9)
GnuTLS version:    3.6.15
Libgcrypt version: 1.8.7


dissect_ssl enter frame #4 (already visited)
packet_from_server: is from server - FALSE
  conversation = 0x7fd900a519e0, ssl_session = 0x0
  record: offset = 0, reported_length_remaining = 261
dissect_ssl3_record: content_type 22 Handshake
dissect_ssl3_handshake iteration 1 type 1 offset 5 length 252 bytes

dissect_ssl enter frame #6 (already visited)
...
```